# coverting .htacess to nginx config

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx-config

This the htacess code

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^watch/(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ search.php?search=$1&page=$2&token=$3
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)/(.*)/?$ watch.php?link=$1&name=$2

RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ privacy.php
RewriteRule ^dmca/?$ dmca.php
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^send/?$ send.php
RewriteRule ^surprise/?$ surprise.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

what should be the correct nginx config?

Comment: Please look into: https://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Comment: i have tried it but watch and search part is not working

Answer (score 0):

nginx configuration

```
error_page 404 /404.php;

location /watch {
  rewrite ^/watch/(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ /search.php?search=$1&page=$2&token=$3;
}

location /video {
  rewrite ^/video/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /watch.php?link=$1&name=$2;
}

location /privacy {
  rewrite ^/privacy/?$ /privacy.php;
}

location /dmca {
  rewrite ^/dmca/?$ /dmca.php;
}

location /contact {
  rewrite ^/contact/?$ /contact.php;
}

location /send {
  rewrite ^/send/?$ /send.php;
}

location /surprise {
  rewrite ^/surprise/?$ /surprise.php;
}
location / {
}
```